# Can't trim textarea value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use an ajax request to send text within a `textarea` to a php file. To send the text, I first need to get the value of the textarea: 
`var text = $("#textarea).val();`
This works fine. The value of the textarea shows up. Then, I do an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'set_articles.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {text: text},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

On the separate php page, the data is being recieved, but the problem is that when I try to break up the text by paragraph, there's a `\n` in the paragraph. For example, if I send these two paragraphs broken up by the enter key:

```
Random paragraph of text.
Random paragraph of text.
```

and use this php code to recieve the info:

```
$text = nl2br($_POST['text']);
$paragraphsArray = preg_split('/\n/', $text);
print_r($paragraphsArray);
```

This is the text that comes out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Random paragraph of text.<br />\nRandom paragraph of text.
)
```

This is what I want to happen:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Random paragraph of text.
    [1] => Random paragraph of text.
)
```

I've already tried trimming the variable `text`, like so:

```
var text = $("#textarea).val();
var newText = $.trim(text);
```

But it returns the same thing:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Random paragraph of text.<br />\nRandom paragraph of text.
)
```

How do I trim the text so that the array works? Is there some other piece of the code that I should post? Let me know.

Comment: Why do you need this line `$text = nl2br($_POST['text']);`?

Comment: I am interested to know how you got a `<br />` out of a textarea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve it in one line with `PHP_EOL` (End Of Line) constant in that situation:

```
$array_data = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use double quotes as "\n" ,not only quote

```
explode("\n",$_POST['text']); //this working

explode('\n',$_POST['text']); //this  not working
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an apostrophe (') occasionally referred to as a single quote as a string delimiter in PHP causes PHP to treat the contents literally, i.e. Escape characters such as \ don't escape anymore, hence it's more useful in your use case here to use double quotes (").

```
$array_data=explode("\n", $_POST['text']);
```

Comment: this is true for `explode` but not the case for `preg_split`. Double quotes is a good habit to get into, though